# Unable to open VMware VMs on Google Cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vmware-workstation

I'm running Workstation Pro 16 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on a Google cloud VM. The vm is [configured for nested virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/nested-virtualization/enabling).

I get the following error:

"Unable to change virtual machine power state. This host supports Intel VT-x, but the Intel VT-x implementation is incompatible with VMware Workstation. This host does not support "Intel EPT" hardware assisted MMU virtualization. VMware Workstation does not support the user level monitor on this host. Module 'MonitorMode' power on failed. Failed to start the virtual machine."

Workstation version: 16.2.4

Hardware compatibility: 16.2

VMware ids cpu as family: 0x6 model: 0x55 stepping: 0x7 (Cascade Lake)

CPU reports VMX flags: vnmi invvpid flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest vapic_reg shadow_vmcs

Comment: IIRC VMware Workstation 12 is that last version to support this configuration.

Comment: @meangrape Has your issue been resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?